# how to generate the same key when using crypto c# 4.0

Tags: c#, .net, key, rijndaelmanaged

hi im trying to encrypt and decrypt string value... i made it by using manual key like...

```
private static byte[] _salt = Encoding.ASCII.GetBytes("123456789abcdefg");
```

and i created key and iv like

```
Rfc2898DeriveBytes rfcDeriveBytes = new Rfc2898DeriveBytes(password, _salt);
rijndaelManaged = new RijndaelManaged();
rijndaelManaged.Key = rfcDeriveBytes.GetBytes(rijndaelManaged.KeySize / 8);
rijndaelManaged.IV = rfcDeriveBytes.GetBytes(rijndaelManaged.BlockSize / 8);
```

but i wanna generate the same key dynamically... i mean how can i generate _salt dynamically...

Comment: It's not clear what you mean by "create the same key dynamically". What do you want to be dynamic? Are you just talking about generating a *random* key? Note that you haven't told us anything about `rfcDeriveBytes`.

Comment: Please explain what you mean with 'same' and 'dynamically' here

Comment: i wanna use key generator instead of _salt

Answer (score 2):

The [`Rfc2898DeriveBytes`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.security.cryptography.rfc2898derivebytes.aspx) class can generate a random salt for you - just [pass the required salt size to the appropriate constructor](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/1bah3ekk.aspx). And don't forget to store the generated salt somewhere safe - it can't be deterministically regenerated, and without it you won't be able to recreate your key and IV for decryption.

```
string password = GetPasswordFromUserInputOrWherever();

using (var deriveBytes = new Rfc2898DeriveBytes(password, 16))  // 16 byte salt
{
    byte[] salt = deriveBytes.Salt;

    // now save the salt somewhere safe
    // you'll need it to generate the same byte sequence when decrypting

    using (var rijndael = new RijndaelManaged())
    {
        rijndael.Key = deriveBytes.GetBytes(rijndael.KeySize / 8);
        rijndael.IV = deriveBytes.GetBytes(rijndael.BlockSize / 8);

        // encrypt...
    }
}
```

And then to decrypt:

```
string password = GetPasswordFromUserInputOrWherever();
byte[] salt = GetSaltFromWhereverYouPreviouslySavedIt();

using (var deriveBytes = new Rfc2898DeriveBytes(password, salt))
using (var rijndael = new RijndaelManaged())
{
    rijndael.Key = deriveBytes.GetBytes(rijndael.KeySize / 8);
    rijndael.IV = deriveBytes.GetBytes(rijndael.BlockSize / 8);

    // decrypt...
}
```

Answer (score 1):

The 'salt' is not secret, you can include it with the encrypted data. You cannot use different salts while encrypting/decrypting, and to be effective you should use a different salt for each message.

You can use the  `System.Security.Cryptography.RandomNumberGenerator` class to create a Salt.

Comment: Note that `Rfc2898DeriveBytes` can generate a salt for you (using `RandomNumberGenerator` internally) if you ask it to.